# DirectX 11 C++ How to rotate a texture coordinate along a point?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to make a whirling effect where the screen is rotating along the center point.

So the end result would be a whirlpool continuously spinning with the center of the screen being the focal point.

I tried to rotate the texture coordinate in the vertex shader by XMMatrixRotationZ, but it rotates the whole screen obviously.

I need to rotate around the center point (0.5, 0.5) but unsure how to go about it.

Comment: [Translate, rotate, translate.](http://ronnqvi.st/translate-rotate-translate/)

Comment: I actually did try that at first. I send in the matrix XMMatrixRotationZ. Then I offset the texture coordinate so it goes to 0.5, 0.5, then I apply rotation by multiplying it by the given matrix, then I translate it back to its original position.

Comment: You need to make the rotation angle dependent on the distance from the centre, otherwise (as you found) you just rotate the whole image.